# Formatting Data

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

Is it possible to format `data` from `bookshelf.js`?

```js
var user = orm.Model.extend({
tableName: 'user',
  roles: function() {
    return this.get('roles').split(',');
   }
});
```

I have a `column` called roles with a comma `delimited` list that I would like returned as an `array`.

Is this possible?